# cocos2d convertToWorldSpace

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm not sure convertToWorldSpace works.

- I have spriteA which is the parent.
- I set it to position 40,40 for example and add it to the scene.
- I have a second spriteB which I set at position 80,80.
- I add spriteB to spriteA.
- I print out the position of spriteB: 80,80.
- I then print [self convertToWorldSpace:spriteB.position]. And, I still get 80,80. 
  Shouldn't spriteB position be different here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your case if you want know the position of your spriteB in the current world you must call the "convertToWorldSpace" methods from its parent (the spriteA) :

> [spriteA convertToWorldSpace:spriteB.position];

The "convertToWorldSpace:" method applies the node's transformation to the given position. You should always call this methods from the parent's sprite.

Comment: Why do you call it from the parent?

Comment: The scene represents the world, so if you ask it to convert any points into its space it'll return the same position. E.g a point at (80, 80) convert into the scene will returns (80, 80). In your case if you convert the spriteB position via the spriteA it'll apply the spriteA transformation over it. I.e your point at (80, 80) with a transformation of (40, 40) (in case where the spriteA's width is about 40px) gives a world position of (120, 120).

Comment: You can find clear explanation from https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/when-to-use-convert-to-nodespace-or-convert-to-worldspace/29402/2?u=cagdasc

Answer (score 2):

ConvertToWorldSpace takes LOCAL node coordinates, and converts them to the world coordinates.
ConvertToNodeSpace takes WORLD coordinates, converts them to the calling node's coordinates.
(If so call `[nodeA convertToWorldSpace:ccp(10,10)]`, it assumes that the (10,10) position is for a child of nodeA)

Basically, To get the world position of any node (in cocos2d 3 or later) use this code:

```
CGPoint worldPosition=[node.parent convertToWorldSpace:node.positionInPoints];
```

I personally made a function so I can use this over and over (add it to the top of any .m/.h file and you will see it)

```
static inline CGPoint
worldPosOfNode(CCNode *node){
    return [node.parent convertToWorldSpace:node.positionInPoints];
}
```

And I use it like this: (myNode can be any cocos2d sprite, label or whatever)

```
CGPoint worldPosition=worldPosOfNode(myNode);
```